# why doesn't my file delete no matter why I do?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, delete-file, streamwriter

```
public void removeLine(String s) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{

    File tempFile = new File("temp.txt");
    FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(sharkFile);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);  
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile, true));

    String currentLine;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        System.out.println(trimmedLine);
        trimmedLine.equals(sharkName);
        if(trimmedLine.equals(sharkName)) continue;
        writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    scanner.close();
    scanner = null;
    reader.close();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    writer = null;
    System.gc();
    if(!sharkFile.delete()){
        System.out.println("Could not delete file d");
        return;
    }
    if(!tempFile.renameTo(sharkFile)){
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");
        return;
    }
}
```

I've gone through numerous threads on stackoverflow and have implemented those changes but my file just won't delete. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you checked user permissions? What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you catching the IO exception somewhere if any ?

Comment: Use `Files.delete()`; at least you'll get a meaningful exception on failure. Also, why `System.gc()`?

Answer (score 1):

The `File` API is notoriously weak on explaining why something fail, e.g. [`File.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) simply returns a `boolean`, and value `false` cannot explain why.

Use the new `Path` API instead.

Also, please (PLEASE!) use try-with-resources.

`Scanner` is slow, so better to use `BufferedReader`, and for writing the lines back with newlines, use a `PrintWriter`.

```
Path sharkPath = sharkFile.toPath();
Path tempPath = Paths.get("temp.txt");
Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset();
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(sharkPath, cs);
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(tempPath, cs, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)))) {
    for (String currentLine; (currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        System.out.println(trimmedLine);
        if (! trimmedLine.equals(sharkName))
            writer.println(currentLine);
    }
}
Files.delete(sharkPath); // throws descriptive exception if cannot delete
Files.move(tempPath, sharkPath); // throws exception if cannot move
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, rename file before delete, it's appearing that you are accessing file name after delete:

```
try {   //rename file first                 
    tempFile.renameTo(sharkFile);

    } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to rename.");                           
                  } 

try {                       
    sharkFile.delete();                             
    } 
catch(Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to delete.");                       
                  }
```

Comment: how would this help?  How is using a RandomAccessFile better than a BufferedReader?